# 5 col layout image gallery - when image is zooomed part of it is "under" another image

Tags: css, positioning

I have a 5 column responsive layout for a gallery page.  I did not code it myself, having found the code for exactly what I wanted somewhere on line.  My coding skills and understanding of CSS positioning are evolving, to put it nicely.

It works well until I zoom an image. The image zooms properly, but the right edge is showing as "under" the image to the zoomed image's right.

Looking for the answer I found that the container must have a relative position and the image to have an absolute position for z-factor to work (or so I understood what I read).  When I set the image position to absolute, each image takes up the entire screen.  I tried a "clear:both" on the hover property to no avail.

The problem exists in any screen width from 550px up - below that the display is single column.

Both the code and the on-page css is valid.  Link is  http://www.artfromny.com/gallery2.html

Any help appreciated; prefer no java solutions since I barely understand the basic concept of it.

Thanks in advance to all of you who spend so much time helping others get the hang of coding.  The last language that I truly understood and used properly was dBase iii so I am kind of struggling here :)

Art

Comment: remove `line-height:0` for `#gallery`

Comment: Please could you check your link which has no images so we can't see the problem and preferably put the code direct into your question (so that in future the question is complete even if your website disappears). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help on how to do this.

Comment: Link is now repaired I apologize for the error.

Comment: Removing line-height:0 on the gallery did not help.